# warning: unable to read history from "/dev/null/.gdb_history":

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

I get this warning when I start debugging. Does anyone know why it's looking in /dev/null for my history.

I know it's some path which was mis-set somewhere but I do not know which?

Any help.

How can I see which environment parameters are passed to GDB by XCode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the current target's settings?